# Pretty print in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a pretty printing function in Clojure that would output data-structures like lists and structs in a human-readable way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

clojure-contrib now has a pprint function.

The API documentation is at http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/pprint-api.html

Answer (score 16):

As Chouser has mentioned, in 1.3 pprint is moved into clojure itself.

http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html#clojure.pprint/pprint

You can (:require clojure.pprint) and start using it.

Answer (score 5):

A pretty printer for Clojure is available [here](http://github.com/tomfaulhaber/cl-format/tree/master).

Answer (score 4):

There was a [post on the Clojure mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/79d07b898b2a0fde/1a8470fc8df44b1d) yesterday, where a few people posted some trial implementations of a pretty-printer.  But as [mipadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28804/mipadi) said, it's not finalized yet.

Answer (score 2):

Not *yet*, but the feature has been discussed and is (presumably) under development by a couple people close to Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, planned but incomplete.  When clojure.contrib.pprint is moved into clojure itself, an update will be posted to its [ticket](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/clojure/tickets/20).