# Why import clojure core.async library separately?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Why do we have to import both `clojure` and `core.async`, as shown in the [core.async readme](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) ?

I thought that all `core.*` libraries were already included in Clojure itself. Or is it to get a different version ?

Comment: What do you mean by import? I only see the dependency information for leiningen in that readme

Comment: Oh, I see... No, not all core libraries are included in clojure itself, there are many contrib libraries which are optional and not part of the main clojure package

Comment: @nberger what are you calling contrib libraries ? The ones in https://github.com/clojure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many "contrib" libraries, like core.async, core.logic, core.match, test.check and many more. The code for the contrib libraries is in the clojure organization in github, so you can see the listing of contrib libraries in https://github.com/clojure?tab=repositories

The choice of name has nothing to do with being part of the main clojure package or not.

Also important, from http://clojure.org/libraries:

> Clojure Contrib is a collection of libraries managed with the same Contributor Agreement, license, and development workflow as Clojure itself. Code in Clojure Contrib can be considered for inclusion in newer versions of Clojure.

Comment: I see, so none of those libraries are included in Clojure ?

Comment: That's right. They are not included in current versions of clojure. But they might be included in a future version. One example is clojure.pprint, it was a contrib library in the beginning. See the different correct answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295458/pretty-print-in-clojure :)